# Why do I lose my PHP session on page change?

Tags: php, session

I had a login system set up that stored a session variable and checked it on each page, but then I moved to a new server.

Now any session variable I set is only available on the page it was set on. I've been searching for reasons why this could happen, and already crossed off permissions issues. Is it possible this has to do with incorrect urls? Everything else on the server appears to be working fine.

I'm running the latest version of PHP and Apache if that helps at all.

Comment: In addition to the session_start() solution you may also want to make user your browser allows cookies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you probably (just assumption) have not got `session_start();` throughout your other pages where required. So for example, create a page called session.php

**Session.php**

```
session_start(); 
if (!isset($_SESSION))
{
 // Enforce logout as session is not set.
}
```

then:

`include "session.php";`

use this snippet through out your pages where your login features are required.

Comment: It was your assumtion but i think he must did it. +1 as we agree and your easy explanation

Answer (score 0):

I've run into issues like this before.  You might try setting a session id when you first start the session using `session_id()`, and then use the same session id before each `session_start()`.

For example:

```
<?php
   session_id(integer);
   session_start();
?>
```